# Table of content in latex

Tags: latex

Could you help me to solve this problem? How I can separate the table of content, list of figure, list of table in different line in content?
Here, my command

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,reqno,openbib]{extreport}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.60in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.2in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

%------------------


\usepackage{titletoc}%% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large \bf{Abstract}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter*}{\noindent\text{Abstract}\hspace{12.5cm} }
\bigskip

\begin{center}
{\Large \bf{Abstrak}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter*}{\noindent\text{Abstrak}\hspace{12.8cm}}
\bigskip

\begin{center}
{\Large \bf{Acknowledgment}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter*}{\noindent\text{Acknowledgement}\hspace{11.0cm}}
\bigskip




\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage

%\newpage


\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Background of the study}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Background of the study}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Please add the class file {extreport.cls}

Comment: Thank you for the respond. I really appreciate :) The class file {extreport.cls} :
http://ossm.utm.my/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extreport.cls

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Working Area using extreport.cls]

Please find the attachment showing answers of your query.

Comment: @Nianrakluz... 
   
 You should click on tick to accept the best answer and upvote for others which helped you.